# Postgres count values from two diffent columns

Tags: postgresql, query, count

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT idusuario,
       to_char(intervalo, 'HH24:MI') AS "intervalo" 
FROM generate_series('2023-06-07 00:00:00', '2023-06-07 23:59:59', '15 minutes'::interval) intervalo JOIN atividadelogin ON TRUE 
GROUP BY idusuario, intervalo ORDER BY intervalo
```

I need a third column with the count of "idusuario" and when the interval value changes, the counter will be reseted.

| idusuario | intervalo | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:00 | 4 |
| 2 | 00:00 | 4 |
| 5 | 00:00 | 4 |
| 6 | 00:00 | 4 |
| 1 | 00:15 | 2 |
| 5 | 00:15 | 2 |

I can't use filter in the count function because i don't know my "intervalo" values.